# How do I get consistent build using visual studio while working with with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, rebuild

I use VS2012, with TFS to manage a multi-project solution. It seems like sometimes when I get the 'latest' and do 'build', not all of the dependencies getting built correctly (I say that because if I do a next run with full 'rebuild', my results differ). I have project dependencies defined correctly (works well for most of the time for my local modifications, except for some scenarios where I have templated code in header files). Is there something that I am missing to make the VS detect the changes correctly?

PS: my dll's go to a different directory than the default $OutDir

Comment: When you say do "build" "rebuild", did you mean the local build in VS or TFS build? Seems if you build the some solution twice without any modification, you will get two different results. And `my dll's go to a different directory than the default $OutDir` did you change the MSBuild OutputPath and OutDir in TFS?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, build and rebuild on local machine in VS. The changes to the $OutDir done on each project, under general tab in project properties

Comment: If so, your issue seems more related to local VS not TFS. Besides, you just need to do a force get latest  from TFS, local VS will automatically detect changes correctly.  If you are worrying about this, which may cause the issue. You could do a  [TFS and VS cache clear](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/)

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, what do you mean by "do a force gt latest from TFS"?. I get the latest by, right-clicking on the solution and opting for get latest version (recursive)

Comment: Right click the file, **advanced -get specific version(select latest)-Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version**.